# How to change the orientation of Softkeyboard

Tags: android, orientation, android-softkeyboard

I customize the softkeyboard, but when we run it on emulator then it run successfully on portrait mode. But when I change the orientation in landscape then keyboard didn't visible. What changes will be done in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change your code, the default emulator has a hard keyboard. So when you put it in landscape mode it doesn't show the softkeyboard.

To solve this, create a new AVD with no keyboard support:

[image]

or edit the config.ini file of existing AVD and put: hw.keyboard=no

Answer (score 0):

add a line in manifest file as following

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

and in the java file override the method **onConfigurationChanged** as

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            // YOU CAN CALL YOUR FUNCTION HERE
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
```

hope this works for you!